# @ManyToOne foreign key NOT NULL field

Tags: java, sql, playframework, ebean, playframework-2.2

In my Entity class I have a field annotated as follows:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "sport_id", nullable=false)
public Sport sport;
```

in SQL it generates

```
sport_id                  bigint,
```

but I expect it to be

```
sport_id                  bigint not null,
```

Is it a bug of Ebean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried setting the optional flag of @ManyToOne?

```
@ManyToOne(optional=false) 
@JoinColumn(name = "sport_id", nullable=false)
public Sport sport;
```

Comment: Thx, Steve! In this way it even works without @JoinColumn annotation.